# conflicting maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, classpath

i have a maven project which is benchmarking several "processing engines". so in my project i have these "engines" added as dependencies. each of these "engines" again has a well-known library in its own depencies, but each engine uses a different version of this well-known library.

so when i run my project, which is starting/stopping these different "processing engines", i obviously run into problems due to these conflicting libraries in the engines' dependencies. i think java only has one of the several libraries loaded and therefore i get NoClassDefFoundErrors when the wrong engine wants to run.

is there an elegant way to avoid this?
is there a (quick &) dirty way to avoid this?

Comment: have you consider to use different profiles?

Comment: i just read about profiles: "They modify the POM at build time". i would need modification at run time. so i think profiles dont help?

Comment: not sure will maven will help you there, but i think you could use jarjar to repack each version of this "well known library" and embed it to engine which use it.

Comment: You need to load each engine and its dependencies in a different address space. There are many solutions to this problem. OSGI, JEE Containers, spawning a new java process for each engine, etc.

Comment: thanks. and which of these solution would you suggest? which is quickest to implement? thanks again.